# Make Postfix accept all login credentials

Tags: postfix, authentication

I have setup a Postfix as a relay for an embedded device with a severely broken STMP implementation. Therefore I need to make Postfix to have AUTH enabled and to accept ANY combination of username and password. As of now I have it relaying my mail to another `relayhost` for the whole subnet, but when the device tries to `AUTH PLAIN`, Postfix answers with `503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled` which make the embedded system interrupt the transmission.

How do I make Postfix accept ANY user:password combination?

Comment: After I installed postfix on my machine, there was no authentication required, so why did you add it if you don't need it?

Comment: Because the device tries to. With erratically changing credentials.

Comment: What kind of client does that?

Comment: A "It compiles. Ship it." house automation server. Does that matter? Changing its software is not an option.

Comment: @MaxRied I was just very curious. I have never heard of such a thing.

Comment: you need create a saslauth mechanism that returns always true. look libsasl2-modules-ldap or libsasl2-modules-sql source package, copy (or change a unsed) a mechanism, and change authenticate method to 'return true'. After run saslauthd with this mechanism with -a option.

Comment: I hoped not to have to do this... I was hoping for some debugging option or a way to check for authentication using an option that allowed me to specify an external program.

Comment: postfix only delegate authentication to a sasl server. postfix can't help you.

Comment: What about making this an answer? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix only delegate authentication to a sasl server. Postfix can't help you.